# $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+ \frac{z}{k})$ converges to $0$ when $\Re (z)<0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> We have a complex number $z$ such that $\Re (z)<0$ and the sequence $ z_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (1+ \frac{z}{k})$. Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_n = 0$.

How to do it? I guess it will be easier to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |z_n|^2 = 0$, it's a trick that usually helps, but even though I thought about if for a longer while, I don't know how to prove it. May somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For every $w$ in $\mathbb C$, $\left|1+w\right|^2=1+2\Re(w)+|w|^2\leqslant\mathrm e^{2\Re(w)+|w|^2}$, hence, for every $n$,
$$
|z_n|^2\leqslant\exp\left(2\Re(z)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k+|z|^2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}\right)\leqslant C(z)\cdot n^{2\Re(z)}.$$

Comment: Just one question: how to show that $exp (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}) \ge n$?

Comment: Two answers: I neither stated this inequality nor used it; this inequality is true and one can prove it comparing the integral $\int\limits_1^n\frac{\mathrm dt}t$ and the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k$.

Comment: So how did you obtain the last inequality? I mean this factor $n^{2 \Re(z)}$?

Comment: By noting that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k\geqslant\log(n)-10^9$.